# SHOPIFY IF statement - Change imagery within div based on product tag for main product

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, shopify

We're having some difficulties writing an IF statement in which selects an img based on the product tags of the main product from the product page.

We need the product colours of the 4 items in the div below to match that of the main product - We thought an IF statement would be the best option for achieving this.

UPDATE: Strict rules based on capitalisation have been checked.

```
    {%- if product.tags contains 'Colour - Black' and 'Leather' -%}
    <div class="FeaturedProduct__Gallery">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="BLACK PRODUCT IMG" width:auto;> 
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="FeaturedProduct__Info">
      <div class="ProductMeta">
        <h1 class="ProductMeta__Title Heading u-h6" style="font-weight: 600">HEADING</h1>
        <div class="ProductMeta__PriceList Heading">
          <span class="ProductMeta__Price Price Text--subdued u-h6">{{ 7999 | money_without_trailing_zeros }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="FeaturedProduct__ViewWrapper">
        <div class="Text--subdued">DESCRIPTION</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ProductForm">
        <button type="button" class="ProductForm__AddToCart Button Button--secondary Button--full">
          <a href="#">BUTTON TEXT</a>
          {%- if section.settings.show_price_in_button -%}
            <span class="Button__SeparatorDot"></span>
            <span>{{ 7999 | money_without_trailing_zeros }}</span>
          {%- endif -%}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
  
    {%- if product.tags contains 'Colour - Tan' and 'Leather' -%}
    <div class="FeaturedProduct__Gallery">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="TAN PRODUCT IMAGE" width:auto;> 
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="FeaturedProduct__Info">
      <div class="ProductMeta">
        <h1 class="ProductMeta__Title Heading u-h6" style="font-weight: 600">HEADING</h1>
        <div class="ProductMeta__PriceList Heading">
          <span class="ProductMeta__Price Price Text--subdued u-h6">{{ 7999 | money_without_trailing_zeros }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="FeaturedProduct__ViewWrapper">
        <div class="Text--subdued">Perfect for Day | Evening</div>
      </div>
      <div class="ProductForm">
        <button type="button" class="ProductForm__AddToCart Button Button--secondary Button--full">
          <a href="#">BUTTON TEXT</a>
          {%- if section.settings.show_price_in_button -%}
            <span class="Button__SeparatorDot"></span>
            <span>{{ 7999 | money_without_trailing_zeros }}</span>
          {%- endif -%}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  {%- endif -%}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest adding a tag for the backend language or frondend framework that's being used here, as that is what you use for the if statements. That way, the right people will see this question.

Answer (score 0):

We've tried all avenues we are aware to get this to function however we fear without js this will not work as intended.

Anyone have a js script in which we can dictate the products rendered by product tag and limit to 4 values?